# summarizing data: how assign a nested group by to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to summarize data that involves nested group-by's and summarizing things by a user ID. There has to be an easier way to do this! This would be easy in SQL...

The data is at a granularity of user x session x activity. Activities are nested within nodes. I need to roll it up to the USER (aka student) level, and count unique activities and unique nodes that satisfy specific criteria.

Start starts as:
[image: example fake data]

```
STUDENT_ID STUDENT_ACTIVITY_SESSION_ID ACTIVITY_START_TIMESTAMP    MINUTES NODE_NAME   ACTIVITY_NAME   IS_PRETEST_ACTIVITY min_node_grade
FredID  gobbledeegook1  11/10/2022  2   Node1   MyActivity1 1   Kindegarten
FredID  gobbledeegook2  3/8/2023    3   Node1   MyActivity1 1   Kindegarten
FredID  gobbledeegook3  12/1/2022   4   Node2   MyActivity2 0   1st Grade
JaniceID    gobbledeegook4  3/1/2023    5   Node3   MyActivity3 1   2nd Grade
JaniceID    gobbledeegook5  3/8/2023    6   Node3   MyActivity4 0   2nd Grade
```

I want to get to:
[image]

```
STUDENT_ID min_pretest min_not_pretest total_min   unique_pretest_activities   unique_non_pretest_activities   UNIQUE_NODES    K_nodes_started 1stgr_nodes_started 2ndgr_and_beyond_nodes_started
FredID  5   4       1   1   2   1   1   0
JaniceID    5   6       1   1   1   0   0   2
```

I first created a dataframe with all the Student ID's and information about them.

Then I aim to add a column that is the result, by student, of grouping by activity ID, and then counting unique activities by student (by whether pretest is true or false). The below kind of works, but then I have to create a temporary df and merge back to df_by_student and assign it to a column... And I have to do this for each column. There has to be an easier way??

```
df_temp=\
df.loc[df['IS_PRETEST_ACTIVITY']==0, ['STUDENT_ID', 'ACTIVITY_ID']].value_counts().reset_index().groupby('STUDENT_ID', as_index=False)['ACTIVITY_ID'].count()
```

For the grades, I first create a by student-node-grade temporary df, df_std_node_grade

```
df_std_node_grade = df[['STUDENT_ID', 'NODE_ID', 'min_node_grade']].value_counts().reset_index().copy(deep=True)
```

Then I can summarize things by grade level

```
df_temp=df_std_node_grade.query("min_node_grade == 'Kindergarten'").groupby('STUDENT_ID', as_index=False)['NODE_ID'].count()
```

...but again I would need to create temporary df's by the student ID and then merge it back...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the data as text (so we can copy-paste-it)?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I'm not sure how. Copy/pasting from Excel makes it an image. I tried making it a table from Word, I tried as text...I tried using the table button, but it will only put in two columns. I read two StackExchange posts about how to do it, but neither works quite right...Hopefully this helps, thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
def my_group_func(x):
    mask_is_pretest = x["IS_PRETEST_ACTIVITY"].eq(1)

    min_pretest = x.loc[mask_is_pretest, "MINUTES"].sum()
    min_not_pretest = x.loc[~mask_is_pretest, "MINUTES"].sum()
    total_min = x["MINUTES"].sum()
    unique_pretest = x.loc[mask_is_pretest, "ACTIVITY_NAME"].nunique()
    unique_not_pretest = x.loc[~mask_is_pretest, "ACTIVITY_NAME"].nunique()
    unique_nodes = x['NODE_NAME'].nunique()
    k_nodes_started = x["min_node_grade"].eq("Kindegarten").sum()
    first_nodes_started = x["min_node_grade"].eq("1st_Grade").sum()
    second_and_beyound_nodes_started = (
        (x["min_node_grade"] != "Kindegarten") & (x["min_node_grade"] != "1st_Grade")
    ).sum()

    return pd.Series({
        "min_pretest": min_pretest,
        "min_not_pretest": min_not_pretest,
        "total_min": total_min,
        "unique_pretest": unique_pretest,
        "unique_not_pretest": unique_not_pretest,
        'unique_nodes': unique_nodes,
        "k_nodes_started": k_nodes_started,
        "first_nodes_started": first_nodes_started,
        "second_and_beyound_nodes_started": second_and_beyound_nodes_started,
    })


print(df.groupby("STUDENT_ID").apply(my_group_func).reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  STUDENT_ID  min_pretest  min_not_pretest  total_min  unique_pretest  unique_not_pretest  unique_nodes  k_nodes_started  first_nodes_started  second_and_beyound_nodes_started
0     FredID            5                4          9               1                   1             2                2                    1                                 0
1   JaniceID            5                6         11               1                   1             1                0                    0                                 2
```

Comment: Almost! Thanks so much for the help! I haven’t seen .eq before, and this is a much better approach. It works except for when the grade levels start – it needs to be unique nodes per grade level. That is, K + 1st + 2nd and beyond = # of unique nodes). So would that be just:

    k_nodes_started = x.loc[x["min_node_grade"]=="Kindergarten", 'NODE_NAME'].nunique()

Comment: Update still struggling to get it by grade level. Is there a way to loop over the dataframe grouped by student AND by grade level, and count the nodes, and have hat be a by-student column? I want: k_nodes_started, first_nodes_started as above

I'm trying:
    df_by_grade= df_activity.groupby('min_node_grade')['NODE_NAME']
    for name, group in df_by_prog_level:
        x = group.nunique() 
        dict_fields["nodes" + name] = x
        pd.Series(dict_fields)
...but this returns each

Comment: @CiviLearner I suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow where you put your sample data and what have you tried and what's failed.

Comment: Yep! Thanks! Really appreciate your help. I used the progress level rather than the grade level, but the question is essentially the same. Here is the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844896/loop-through-a-group-by-aggregate-and-make-new-columns-based-on-the-groups